# Tabbed page custom renderer on Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, toolbar, tabbedpage

How can I achieve something like the top bar in the screenshot (**"Totale Regioni Province"**) using a tabbed page custom renderer? Right now I'm using "fake tabs" made of three different labels.

I need to change font family, font size and padding of the tabs.

[image: "Totale Regioni Province" bar]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing with custom renderer, I tried changing tabbar.xml but it's not what I am looking for since I want to apply the bar design from the photo to this specific page and not the entire app. @EliasJohannes

Comment: In this case you can create a custom control and then a custom renderer specifically for this control. There are tons of tutorials on the web and it's pretty straight forward. After you made the custom control you can use it only when you need it and stick to the standard renderer for your other cases.

Comment: What tutorial would you recommend to a beginner in custom control and then a custom renderer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to change the font of tab page, you could use the custom renderer to reset it.

MyTabbedPageRenderer.cs:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MainPage), typeof(MyTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace TabbedPageDemo.Droid
{
class MyTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
{
    public MyTabbedPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TabbedPage> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement == null || e.OldElement != null)
            return;

        TabLayout tablayout = (TabLayout)ViewGroup.GetChildAt(1);
        Android.Views.ViewGroup vgroup = (Android.Views.ViewGroup)tablayout.GetChildAt(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < vgroup.ChildCount; i++)
        {
            Android.Views.ViewGroup vvgroup = (Android.Views.ViewGroup)vgroup.GetChildAt(i);
            Typeface fontFace = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(this.Context.Assets, "Trashtalk.ttf");
            for (int j = 0; j < vvgroup.ChildCount; j++)
            {
                Android.Views.View vView = (Android.Views.View)vvgroup.GetChildAt(j);
                if (vView.GetType() == typeof(Android.Support.V7.Widget.AppCompatTextView) || vView.GetType() == typeof(Android.Widget.TextView))
                {
                    //here change textview style
                    TextView txtView = (TextView)vView;
                    txtView.TextSize = 14f;
                    txtView.SetTypeface(fontFace, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I use a Tabbed page template project for example.

[image]

**Update:**

Create a Font folder in Resource. Add .ttf file and myfont.xml in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
 <font android:font="@font/Samantha"
          android:fontStyle="normal"
          android:fontWeight="400"
          app:font="@font/Samantha"
          app:fontStyle="normal"
          app:fontWeight="400"/>

</font-family>
```

[image]

Style.xml

```
<style name="MyTabLayout" parent="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout">
<item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyTabTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button">
<item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/myfont</item>
</style>
```

Apply styles in Tabbar.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
app:tabGravity="fill"
app:tabMode="fixed" 
style="@style/MyTabLayout"/>
```

Comment: what if I wanted to use a custom_tab_layout.xml to change each tab appearance?

Comment: I have updated my reply. Please check it.