# Change font size of tabs in a TabbedPage

Tags: xamarin.forms

Is there anyway to changed the font size of the ContentPage? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXN8z.png)

Example is that, the last Tab. SUMMARY is cut and I want to set the font size to small.

```
 <TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test.ViewModels" 
            xmlns:model="clr-namespace:Test.Models"
            
            Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor="Transparent"
            x:Class="Test.Views.MainPage">
    
    <ContentPage Title="Delivery">
        
    </ContentPage>
    <ContentPage Title="Pending">

    </ContentPage>
    <ContentPage Title="Success">

    </ContentPage>
    <ContentPage Title="Failed">

    </ContentPage>
    <ContentPage Title="Summary">

    </ContentPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

I tried adding this:

```
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <Label Text="This is my Title" FontSize="12" TextColor="White" />
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

But doesn't do anything.

Comment: if you are asking about the size of the Font is the Tabs, then that has nothing to do with the ContentPage

Comment: Oh I see, yes. I was asking about the size of the Font. Is there any alternative to that? Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, There isn't a "cross platform" way to change the tab's font size. But you can do it by making changes on each platform. For example, [On Android change tab font size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49716473/199364), which refers to [change tab style](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35555554/199364).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the tab title as the screenshot you privided. You could try the code below to set the TabMode, TabGravity in custom renderer.

```
 [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), 
typeof(CustomTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace App15.Droid
{
class CustomTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
{
    private TabLayout tabLayout = null;
    public CustomTabbedPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.TabbedPage> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        this.tabLayout = (TabLayout)this.GetChildAt(1);        
        tabLayout.TabMode = TabLayout.ModeScrollable;
        tabLayout.TabGravity = TabLayout.GravityFill;
    }
}
}
```

Normally, we could set the TextSize in tabbed page custom renderer. But sometimes we would miss the different types if TextView. So i think the way above would be better. You could also check the way to set the TextSize in custom renderer.
[Tabbed page custom renderer on Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62791372/tabbed-page-custom-renderer-on-xamarin-forms/62811424#62811424)

When TabbedPage use `android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"` to set the tabs in the bottom, the renderer above does not work. You could refer to teh solution in the link below.
[How to change Tabbar text size when using TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom" in Xamarin Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52942280/how-to-change-tabbar-text-size-when-using-tabbedpage-toolbarplacement-bottom-i)